# How to use a c# extension method to add to list as well as create the list

Tags: c#, list, extension-methods

When I use the below method, when this list is null, the list is created and a record is added, but the list is still null outside of the method.

However if the list is already created then I see the list grow outside the method.

```
    public static void Add(this List<Setting> Settings, object Name, object Value)
    {
        if(null==Settings)
        {
            Settings = new List<Setting>();
        }

        var item = Settings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.ToLower() == Name.ToString().ToLower());
        if (null != item)
        {
            //overwrite the value of an existing item
            item.Value = Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            //Add the new Setting to the list
            Settings.Add(new Setting(Name.ToString(), Value.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like an anti-pattern to me. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx: "In general, we recommend that you implement extension methods sparingly and only when you have to. Whenever possible, client code that must extend an existing type should do so by creating a new type derived from the existing type. For more information, see Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)."

Comment: What really sticks out at me is the fact that it's an extension method on an object that is trying to reassign itself. If your code is trying to set `this` to something else it's not a good thing.

Comment: It's more intuitive to me to have this method throw on a null reference since it makes no sense to add something to nothing.

Comment: I actually agree with the first comment I think the List<Setting> field in the class that I haven't shown, should be replaced by a new class that inherits the List functionality or encapsulating a List<Setting>.

Comment: Another simple way of looking at it: `Settings` is not a `ref` parameter. (Therefore, this question is not specific to extension methods, except that in an extension method, the `this` paremeter can't be made a `ref` parameter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension method is not the way to go here. Reassigning an object reference should never be the duty of the object itself. That should be the responsibility of the caller/consumer of the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way arguments are passed to methods in C#. The `Settings` is a **copy** of the references you called the extension method on. It points to the same object, but it's a different reference. So if you assign a new value to it, the outer reference remains unchanged.

You might consider changing the return type from `void` to `List<Settings>`.

Then you can use:

```
settings = settings.Add(name, value);
```

Additional benefit is ability to chain `Add`:

```
settings = settings.Add(name1, value1)
                   .Add(name2, value2)
                   .Add(name3, value3);
```